# How can I import a Swift Static Library into another Swift Static Library

Tags: ios, swift, static

I have a workspace containing three Projects (in addition to the Pods project):

```
-A (includes a static library target named 'A')
-B (includes a static library target named 'B')
-App (includes an iOS Application target named 'App')
```

Project A and B each contain a swift static library.
I want to have libA as a dependency of libB and I want the App target to have both libA and libB as dependencies.

All of the projects have custom build configurations (the same configurations for all of them).

I added both libA.a and libB.a as linked binaries to the App target. But when I try to build the App I get an error in target B:

`No such module A` on the line `import A`

How can I have a swift static library import another static library from a different project?

A.swift file:

```
//A.swift

import Foundation

public class A {

   public static func add(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {

      return x + y
   }
}
```

B.swift file:

```
//B.swift

import Foundation
import A // Here I get the error: No such Module 'A'

public class B {

    public static func multiply(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {

        var result: Int = 0

        for _ in 0..<y {
            result = A.add(x: result, y: x)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

These images show how my projects are setup:
Project A:
[image: Projet A]

Project B:
[image: Project B]

Project App:
[image: Project App1]

[image]

The 2 Schemes for the target App:
[image]

Comment: can you provide us a real code example, please?

Comment: @ItaloJosé My question is about project structure, not any particular code, but I've updated the question to further explain the issue